# <ul> in Bootstrap can't be centered when justify-content-center is applied to <ul> when <ul> is within a row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is my code (only body)

```
  <body>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row">

          <ul class="nav justify-content-center nav-tabs"> 
            <li class="nav-item"> 
              <a class="nav-link" href="/home.php">Home</a> 
            </li> 
            <li class="nav-item"> 
              <a class="nav-link" href="/login.php">Log In</a> 
            </li> 
            <li class="nav-item"> 
              <a class="nav-link" href="/logout.php">Log Out</a> 
            </li> 
          </ul>
     

      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
```

Display :

[image]

I can however , center ul when i place ul within a column. Is there a specific reason why my above code could not center ul

EDIT :

If i remove row from the code, I could use justify-content-center on ul.My question however still stands as I could not explain the behavior when row is present

```
<body>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">

  
 
          <ul class="nav justify-content-center nav-tabs"> 
            <li class="nav-item"> 
              <a class="nav-link" href="/home.php">Home</a> 
            </li> 
            <li class="nav-item"> 
              <a class="nav-link" href="/login.php">Log In</a> 
            </li> 
            <li class="nav-item"> 
              <a class="nav-link" href="/logout.php">Log Out</a> 
            </li> 
          </ul>
     

    </div>

</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this instead,**

### First Method

please add `flex-basis:100%;` to  for align `<ul>` center.

```css
ul{
  flex-basis:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center"> 
          <li class="nav-item"> 
            <a class="nav-link" href="/home.php">Home</a> 
          </li> 
          <li class="nav-item"> 
            <a class="nav-link" href="/login.php">Log In</a> 
          </li> 
          <li class="nav-item"> 
            <a class="nav-link" href="/logout.php">Log Out</a> 
          </li> 
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

## Second Method

please add `justify-content-center` to **row** class to align `<ul>` center instead of adding to `<ul>` tag.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
          <li class="nav-item"> 
            <a class="nav-link" href="/home.php">Home</a> 
          </li> 
          <li class="nav-item"> 
            <a class="nav-link" href="/login.php">Log In</a> 
          </li> 
          <li class="nav-item"> 
            <a class="nav-link" href="/logout.php">Log Out</a> 
          </li> 
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Yeap this works. But why it does not work when done on <ul> directly though?

Comment: You can align center by adding to <ul>  `flex-basis:100%;`. try this :)

Answer (score 0):

The `ul` itself is not centered, so using `.justify-content-center` will center its child `li` elements only inside the `ul`, while it itself remains on the left. Add `.justify-content-center` to the `ul`'s parent element (the row div) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<div class="row">

    <ul class="nav justify-content-center nav-tabs" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/home.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/login.php">Log In</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/logout.php">Log Out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Why is the width of <ul> not 100%? Given that <ul> is a block level element , the width will cover the content area width of the parent right? Also , given that <ul> already has nav class, wouldn't that already made it a flex element ?